# R: Import csv-file and keep symbols

Tags: r, csv, import

I like to import a csv-file (as data.frame) and keep the symbols like "+", "-", "/" instead of having them transformed into "." , because they are important indicators for my work.(I am using a file someone else created and these symbols indicate booleans)

```
flow_df <- read.csv(file)
```

Example col-name in File to import:
"Lymph/Single/CD3/CD4/A+B+C+D-"

should not be transformed to:
"Lymph.Single.CD3.CD4.A.B.C.D."

Comment: Probably, you could use `flow_df <- read.csv(file, check.names=FALSE)`. However, note that it will be a pain in the neck to work with such data as you will have to use back ticks to refer to the variables.

Comment: Thanks! Does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rivka,

Use

```
read.csv('file.txt',check.names = F)
```

or

```
read.table('file.txt',check.names = F,sep = ',',header = T)
```